# Can we fetch records from a table through cursor and then insert those records in a remote table through remote package calling?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to pull some records from source table resides in one db and then insert those records in a remote table through remote package calling and again after inserting the records in remote table control should come and delete those particular records in source table.

"CODE"

--Main Procedure

```
Create or replace Procedure P1
is 
l_count           NUMBER;
l_proc_status     VARCHAR2 (100);
CURSOR c_core_data
  IS
     SELECT a.ROWID
       FROM table_1 a
      WHERE creation_date < SYSDATE - 10;
  TYPE xx_rowid_type IS TABLE OF c_core_data%ROWTYPE
     INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  xx_rowid_table    xx_rowid_type;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT (1)
       INTO l_count
       FROM table_1
      WHERE creation_date < SYSDATE - 10;
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
     THEN
        l_count := 0;
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
        l_count := 0;
  END;
  IF l_count > 1
  THEN
     schema.table_2@dblink(); -- remote procedure call for archive LOB table


     BEGIN
        SELECT process_status
          INTO l_proc_status
          FROM schema.Status_table@dblink
               a
         WHERE     a.table_name = 'table_1'
               AND a.ROWID =
                      (SELECT MAX (b.ROWID)
                         FROM schema.Status_table@dblink
                              b
                        WHERE a.table_name = b.table_name);
     EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
           RAISE ARCHIEVE_EXP;
     END;

     IF l_proc_status = 'FAILED'
     THEN
        l_proc_str := 'schema.table_2';

        RAISE ARCHIEVE_EXP;
     END IF;
  END IF;


  OPEN c_core_data;

  LOOP
     FETCH c_core_data BULK COLLECT INTO xx_rowid_table LIMIT 100;


     EXIT WHEN xx_rowid_table.COUNT = 0;


     FORALL idx IN xx_rowid_table.FIRST .. xx_rowid_table.LAST
        DELETE FROM table_1 b
              WHERE b.ROWID = xx_rowid_table (idx).ROWID;

     COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c_core_data;



  COMMIT;
END;
```

--Remote Procedure

```
Create or replace Procedure schema.table_2
is
l_sql_errm     VARCHAR2 (1000);
CURSOR c_x
  IS
     SELECT a.ROWID
       FROM schema.table_1@dblink A
      WHERE creation_date < SYSDATE - 10;

  TYPE xx_c_type IS TABLE OF c_x%ROWTYPE
     INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  xx_row_table   xx_c_type;

  CURSOR c_gtt
  IS
     SELECT a.ROWID
       FROM table_1_GTT a;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_x;

  LOOP
     FETCH c_x BULK COLLECT INTO xx_row_table LIMIT 1000;

     EXIT WHEN xx_row_table.COUNT = 0;

     FOR idx IN xx_row_table.FIRST .. xx_row_table.LAST
     LOOP
        INSERT INTO schema.table_1_GTT (
                       DERIVED_RESELLER_CCOID,
                       DERIVED_DISTI_CCOID)
           SELECT DERIVED_RESELLER_CCOID,
                  DERIVED_DISTI_CCOID
             FROM schema.table_1@dblink
                  a
            WHERE a.ROWID = xx_row_table (idx).ROWID;
     END LOOP;


     FOR idx IN c_gtt
     LOOP
        INSERT INTO schema.table_2(
                       DERIVED_RESELLER_CCOID,
                       DERIVED_DISTI_CCOID,
                       PURGE_DATE)
           SELECT DERIVED_RESELLER_CCOID,
                  DERIVED_DISTI_CCOID,
                  SYSDATE
             FROM schema.table_1_GTT a
            WHERE a.ROWID = idx.ROWID;
     END LOOP;

     COMMIT;
  END LOOP;



  CLOSE c_x;

  COMMIT;


  INSERT INTO Status_table
       VALUES ('table_1',
               'COMPLETE',
               SYSDATE,
               'Success');

  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     l_sql_errm := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 1000);



     INSERT INTO Status_table
          VALUES ('table_1',
                  'FAILED',
                  SYSDATE,
                  l_sql_errm);

     COMMIT;
```

END;

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Can we? Yes, we can. For example (see comments within the code):

```
begin
  -- loop through all employees. EMPNO is a primary key column
  for cur_r in (select empno, ename, job from emp) loop

    -- call the remote procedure over a database link. Pass values fetched by the cursor
    remote_package.remote_procedure@db_link_name(cur_r.empno, cur_r.ename, cur_r.job);

    -- delete that employee from the table
    delete from emp where empno = cur_r.empno;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Instead of passing every column in the remote procedure parameter , can we declare  a table type variable or ref cursor kind of things to do that?

Comment: It gets real hairy really fast. This kind of work involves two different databases with different data dictionaries, and PL/SQL doesn't allow you to reference a remote type directly with DB link syntax. Perhaps it might be possible by defining matching local and remote types with matching Object ID (a special feature for data cartridges). But it's probably not worth all of the hassle; it's easier to pass the full list of columns.